Find all telephone numbers using RegEx
I am trying to extract all uk telephone numbers found in an email.
I have used a web based tool (RegEx101) and found a regular expression that checks if a string is a UK phone number:
/(^\+[0-9]{2}|^\+[0-9]{2}\(0\)|^\(\+[0-9]{2}\)\(0\)|^00[0-9]{2}|^0)([0-9]{9}$|[0-9\-\s]{10}$)/mg

I put 2 uk numbers into the tool on different lines:
01234567890
07911111111

RegEx101 finds the 2 numbers.
How do I get the search to find these inside other text such as:
Landline 01234567890 (Personal)
Mobile 07911111111 (Work)


On Regex101, are you using PCRE or did you select .NET?

BTW, Regexes are great and all, but phone-numbers have their own nasty rules (especially non-E.164, "locally formatted" phone-numbers which have punctuation, parentheses and more which won't work with your regex) so I recommend you look at Google's libphonenumber: https://www.nuget.org/packages/libphonenumber-csharp/ (it's the same library Android uses for processing phone-numbers).

Finding those numbers in text is straightforward, but you have more problems than that. Your regex won't find 01234 567890, or +44 1234 567890, or 0208 123 4567 or any of the other commonly used formats for UK numbers. Non-UK numbers are a whole new can of worms.

Hi. Thanks for the help.. I used PCRE. I understand the limitations and I am new to Reg Expressions so I am trying things out. The RegEx is suitable for me and it works with just the numbers but I would like it to work exactly the same if there are words before and after the telephone numbers.

Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Phone Numbers there are many many valid UK phone numbers (and formats thereof) that do not match your Regex pattern.

Thanks Charlieface. I will look into a better RegEx expression. However, could somebody please tell me how I can change the one I have given so it can find the same pattern in the middle of strings?

The ^ in your regex requires that the match be at the beginning of the line, so it can never match anywhere else. It's also completely overly complicated. A 10-digit number can be matched with \d{10}. You can use (^|\s)(\d{10})($|\s), which matches either the beginning of a line or a space, a 10-digit number, and either the end of a line or a space, and matches all the examples you've posted. Note that your regex will also match something that isn't a phone number, such as a part number, id number, or any random group of 10 digits, which means it isn't really parsing out phone numbers.

Also note that the title of your question is misleading, as you're not actually trying to match phone numbers, and have refused to listen to those telling you that you're not doing so. You're simply trying to match a 10-digit number without any spaces or other characters within it, which is not a phone number.

You need to provide specific requirements for the pattern. Right now, the regex even matches almost empty strings, starting with 0 and then having 9 spaces/hyphens. In order to match phone numbers you should describe what exact formats you expect to match since just matching 10 digit sequences is a basic regex thing.

Better Rename that Question to "Find some telephone numbers using RegEx" then

try this /(\(\+[0-9]{2}\)\(0\)|00[0-9]{2}|0)([0-9]{9}$|[0-9\-\s]{10})/gm

You don't need all that noise. See my comment above

Ah, when I started looking at this that comment wasn't there.

I never said it was there when you wrote this. :-) I just pointed out that your regex is much too noisy and all of that repetition is totally unnecessary. The OP is simply matching a 10-digit number - nothing more complex is needed.

It also matches strings like 0----------. Or, 0 followed with 9 spaces.
